# C#/WPF Retrieve textbox input value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my app, I am trying to get the input value of a textbox for use later but I'm unable to successfully get the value. Any ideas where I have made a mistake or how to fix it? Below is my code, if more code is needed, feel free to ask. Thank you in advance.

**View Model:**

```
namespace Creator.ViewModels
{
    public class CreatureCreatorViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public CreatureModel CreateNewCreature { get; set; }

        /*Variables to "get" input data*/
        private string creatureName;
        public string CreatureName
        {
            get { 
                return creatureName; 
            }
            set
            {
                if(!string.Equals(creatureName, value))
                {
                    creatureName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CreatureName");
                }
            }
        }

        public CreatureCreatorViewModel(NavigationStore navigationStore)
        {
            CreateNewCreature = new CreatureModel().NewCreature(creatureName);
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="CreatureNameBox" Text="{Binding Path=CreatureName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="16" Margin="150,0,150,16" MaxLines="1" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,3,5,3" MaxLength="100"/>
```

**ViewModelBase:**

```
namespace Creator.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string  propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public virtual void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `CreatureCreatorViewModel` instance is assigned as the `DataContext` of the view, where your texbox lives? The simpliest way to check this is to initialize `CreatureCreatorViewModel.creatureName` with some test value then verify that this value will be visible in the TextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simple test using the source code you provided. And I could see that it's normal as shown in the image below.

[image]

I put the sample on GitHub to compare with your source code.
[Here](https://github.com/devncore/stackoverflow-sample/tree/main/src/answers/textbox-binding-test-app)

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CreatureName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatureName}"/>
```